# Draw background image in libgdx without moving the sprite along with the camera

Tags: java, libgdx, game-engine

I have a background image that I wish to stay in the same position on the screen. So, as I advance with my spaceship and move the camera with the spaceship the same background image would stay on the screen. Is there a way to draw the backgroung image on the screen without having to move it along with the camera ? Like for example using a special layer or something so no aditional matrix translations are needed to also move the BG image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `camera.unproject(Vector2 vector)` function in the libGDX camera class. To put the background image at a certain location on the screen you just need to unproject it every time you are drawing and draw onto the sprite batch from the unprojected co-ordinates. E.g:

```
Vector2 position  = new Vector2(10,10); //Can be anything, the x and y of where the background should be
camera.unproject(position); //Unproject the co-ordinates to the position of the camera, this will be stored back in the position vector

batch.draw(background, position.x, position.y); //You can then draw to your sprite batch from the unprojected co-ordinates
```